# Import Proto files to Bazel build from Envoy

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel, envoyproxy

I am writing a C++ program and it requires the Ext_auth.proto from Envoy - https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/api/envoy/config/filter/http/ext_authz/v2/ext_authz.proto

How can I import the proto file to Bazel build? And how to generate the pb files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Envoy maintained repo: https://github.com/envoyproxy/data-plane-api

It contains Envoy protos and instrumented with Bazel.